# VB .Net Get the integers variable's name that has the loweset value

Tags: vb.net, variables, integer

I wish to obtain the variable's name that contains the lowest value from an array of integer variables.

```
Dim var1 As Integer = 101
Dim var2 As Integer = 14
Dim var3 As Integer = 75
Dim var4 As Integer = 8
Dim var5 As Integer = 9

Dim vals As Integer() = {var1, var2, var3, var4, var5}

Dim smallest As Integer = Integer.MaxValue

For Each element As Integer In vals
    smallest = Math.Min(smallest, element)
Next
```

smallest = 8, however how to I obtain the name "var4"?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why do you need the variable's Name and not its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the variable name because it's not part of the array that was filled with the values of those variables. If the index is not enough and you really need the name, you should consider to use a different collection: `Dictionary(Of String, Int32)`:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)
dict.Add("var1", 101)
dict.Add("var2", 14)
dict.Add("var3", 75)
dict.Add("var4", 8)
dict.Add("var5", 9)

Dim lowestValuePair = dict.OrderBy(Function(pair) pair.Value).First()
Dim name As String = lowestValuePair.Key   ' var4
Dim value As Int32 = lowestValuePair.Value ' 8
```

I'm using the LINQ methods `OrderBy` and `First` here, so you need to add `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: Dictionaries are efficient when doing lookups by key. The overhead of filling and enumerating the hash table is not paid off here. It would be more efficient to use a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32))` here.

Answer (score 2):

Names of local variables are only known in your Visual Basic text until compile time. They are lost in the compiled application. I.e., you cannot access them at run time.

You could use tuples to store a name as string together with a number.

```vb
Dim namedIntegers As (name As String, value As Integer)() = {
    ("var1", 101),
    ("var2", 14),
    ("var3", 75),
    ("var4", 8),
    ("var5", 9)
}

Dim smallest = namedIntegers.OrderBy(Function(x) x.value).First()
Console.WriteLine($"Smallest variable is {smallest.name} = {smallest.value}")
Console.ReadKey()
```

Prints

> Smallest variable is var4 = 8

`Function(x) x.value` is a [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the *index* in the array, but not the variable name:

```
Dim var1 As Integer = 101
Dim var2 As Integer = 14
Dim var3 As Integer = 75
Dim var4 As Integer = 8
Dim var5 As Integer = 9

Dim vals As Integer() = {var1, var2, var3, var4, var5}

Dim smallest As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
Dim smallestIndex As Integer = 0

For Each i As Integer = 0 To vals.Length - 1
    If vals(i) < smallest Then
       smallestIndex = i
       smallest = vals(i)
    End If    
Next
```

Variable names are for use by programmers. If you're exposing them to the user other than for error reporting you're doing something wrong.

Maybe you want an array like this:

```
Dim var(5) As Integer = {0, 101, 14, 75, 8, 9}
```

Now the index also implies the variable.